# body parser and html depreceated

Tags: body-parser

I am trying to send data from form to HTML. Having looked at most of the stackoverflow posts it has not worked. my code in `app.js` is as follows:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const PORT = 3000;
app.use(bodyparser({"extended":true}));
```

I am getting the following error:

> express deprecated req.host: Use req.hostname instead node_modules\body-parser\index.js:100:29

Please let me know what steps to take.

Comment: This seems like an error in the body-parser code, not something you can fix. Also, please could you format your question better and improve the title? See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this

```
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
```